# Windows .bat file doesn't execute its sequence

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created a simple install.bat file into my application folder, to execute its thing on windows.

But it only executes the first line of the .bat file.

Is there something that I need to add so it continues after the first one is done?

```
copy something somewhere
move something somewhereelse
gem install etc
```

Above are the type of commands that are in the .bat.

Do I need to anything something inbetween?

Comment: A batch file should keep doing each line in sequence, until you either explicitly exit or something blows up severely hard and kills the command interpreter.

Comment: Add "pause" (without quotes) as the last line of your batch file and it will leave the command window open so you can check for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Is the first command in your batch file actually a `copy` command, or is it a command that's running another batch file?

Running a batch file from another by simply using the second batch file;s name will not return to the calling batch file.

If you want one batch file to invoke another and return you have to use the `call` command.

Answer (score 1):

Are you overwriting a file? If so you'll need to add the /Y to the copy command to supress the prompt that asks if you want to overwrite the file.

Use the /h parameter to get help on the copy command. It will show this usage and some others.

Answer (score 0):

As written above, all three lines will execute. I imagine that the second and third lines are failing. You should capture the output which will explain why those lines failed.

Comment: in fact I've ran it on the prompt it doesn't fail. The gem install takes a while its probably not locking and its trying to execute the other commands without being able to.